# Wildcards don't work in title searches

Tags: feature-request, search, wildcards

I search for: `title:change` - I get results
I search for: `title:chang*` - No results
I search for: `chang*` - I get results (body & title)

Wildcard searches in the title should work or the text of ["How Do I Search?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) info page should be changed.

Comment: I think "chang" is recognised as a typo for "change", not that wildcards are accepted.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy wildcards wont´t work for `body:` or `title:` searches

Comment: @Jehof: I see what you're talking about now, I was thinking of Google search where wildcards in the middle of words don't work as expected.